# Want to show Device id on Every Marker, Device id received from the server

Tags: android, json, performance, android-layout, android-fragments

Want to show **Uniqueid** on Every Marker, uniqueid received from the server.
i think to set the TAG of marker the every marker uniqueid show but i try it several time but fail to implement..
please help me how set every marker uniqueid on every Marker..

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static MainActivity instance;
private ArrayList<LatLng> latLngList;
private static final int ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
GoogleMap mMap;
int FirstTimeMapIniciate = 0;
double latitude = 0;
double longitude = 0;
private GoogleApiClient mLocationClient;
private com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener mListener;
private Marker marker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    latLngList = new ArrayList<>();

    if (servicesOK()) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        if (initMap()) {

            mLocationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();

            mLocationClient.connect();


            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Map Connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.mapTypeNone:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
            break;
        case R.id.mapTypeNormal:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            break;
        case R.id.mapTypeSatellite:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            break;
        case R.id.mapTypeTerrain:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            break;
        case R.id.mapTypeHybrid:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            break;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public boolean servicesOK() {

    int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        return true;
    } else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable, this, ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST);
        dialog.show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connect to mapping service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return false;
}

private boolean initMap() {
    if (mMap == null && FirstTimeMapIniciate == 0) {
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mMap = mapFragment.getMap();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    }
    return (mMap != null);
}

private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng, float zoom) {
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom);
    mMap.moveCamera(update);
}


public void showCurrentLocation(MenuItem item) {
    Location currentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
            .getLastLocation(mLocationClient);
    if (currentLocation == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Couldn't connect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(
                currentLocation.getLatitude(),
                currentLocation.getLongitude()
        );
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                latLng, 10
        );
        mMap.moveCamera(update);
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Ready to map!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    mListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            LatLng latLng1 = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();
            mp = new MarkerOptions();
            mp.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                    location.getLongitude()));

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Location : " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (FirstTimeMapIniciate == 0) {
                gotoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 15);

                FirstTimeMapIniciate = 1;

            }
            AppUtill.UniqueId();
            new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://13.7/hajjapi/api/GPSLocator/GetLocations");

            if (AppStatus.getInstance(getContext()).isOnline()) {

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Turn On your WIFI ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }


        }
    };
    LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create();
    request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    request.setInterval(1000);
    request.setFastestInterval(1000);
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationClient, request, mListener);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}


class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(data);

                latLngList.clear();


                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    ModelClass modelClass = new Gson().fromJson(jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).toString(), ModelClass.class);


                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(modelClass.getLatitude()), Double.parseDouble(modelClass.getLongitude())); // Use your server's methods
                    latLngList.add(latLng);

                }


                return true;

            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;


    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Receicve data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (result == false) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        AddPointer();

    }



}
private void AddPointer() {
    try {
        if (marker != null) {
            mMap.clear();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Remove", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        for (LatLng object : latLngList)

            marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("User Name").position(object).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.female4)));

        System.out.println(marker.getPosition() + "  Marker position.......");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public MainActivity() {
    instance = this;
}

public static Context getContext() {
    return instance;
}

  }
```

Here is my Model Class

```
public class ModelClass {

@SerializedName("longi")
public String longitudeServer;

@SerializedName("lati")
public String latitudeServer;

@SerializedName("uniqueid")
public String uniqueidSserver;

public ModelClass(){
    // blank constructor is required
}

public String getLongitude(){
    return longitudeServer;
}


public String getLatitude(){
    return latitudeServer;
}


public String getUniqueId(){
    return uniqueidSserver;
}

}
```

> Here is my Json data

`[{"longi":"74.3230343","lati":"31.5004135","uniqueid":"25c04146a064bce9"},{"longi":"74.3230899","lati":"31.5003008","uniqueid":"78cd7908e14a38d6"}]`

Comment: Anyone help me pleaseeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee......

Comment: Help me please anyone have solution?

Comment: What do you mean by show it on every marker?  On the info window?

Comment: Nasch i want to show UniqueId on every marker....Unique received from the server

Comment: Yes, I understand the unique id part, I'm asking what you mean by "on the marker".  As far as I know Google Maps has no mechanism to overlay text directly on top of a marker.  Here is the guide for map markers: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker . I think the best you can do is set the marker title.  I think you can also open the info window of multiple markers at the same time programatically rather than waiting for the user to tap the marker.

Comment: yes i want to set every unique id on the title of the markers but i try many time but not make the logic how to implement it.
every uniqueid against the longitude and latitude received from the server
please help me if you know what i do?

Comment: The code to add a marker looks right, what is it doing incorrectly?  Note that unless you do something different the title won't show until you tap on the marker.

Comment: yes Nasch in this time i simply draw markers on the screen but i want to display Unique id of every marker in the title of the markers.
and also set different images on every marker.
i try to implement with different logics but fail to implement if you know please help me Advanced thanks nasch..

Comment: here is json data that i also received Uniqueid of every device..
[{"longi":"74.3230343","lati":"31.5004135","uniqueid":"25c04146a064bce9"},{"longi":"74.3230899","lati":"31.5003008","uniqueid":"78cd7908e14a38d6"}]

Comment: I don't know what "fail to implement" means.  Please explain exactly what the incorrect behavior is.  And if you want to show some JSON it's best to put it in the question where it will be easier to read.

Comment: I already add the JSON in this question in last.
i don't able to add uniqueId's in every Markers, means i don't able to make logic how to set every unique id in every markers title.
may be set the TAG to every marker but i don't know how to set TAG.

Comment: I've asked twice now for an explanation of the incorrect behavior and you just keep saying you can't do it.  If you can explain what is going wrong I can try to help but otherwise there is nothing I can do.  Repeating that the logic is wrong isn't helping.

Comment: Here is my code to add markers according to longitude and latitude that received from the server..
private void AddPointer() {
    try {
        if (marker != null) {
            mMap.clear();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Remove", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        for (LatLng object : latLngList)

            marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("User Name").position(object).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.female4)));   
}
I already write it in the question
but i want to know how to set Unique id on these markers title

Comment: I already write this code in the question it will draw all the markers on the screen but problem is how to set uniqueid in the markers title?

Comment: or explain me how i set every marker uniqueid on every markers?
uniqueid received from the server

Comment: Instead of setting the marker title to "User Name" set it to the unique id.

Comment: I have Uniqueids in this ArrayList name is 'uniqueids' how i map the id's on every markers title?

Comment: Here is my List of unique ID's how i set these id's in the title of marker instead of User Name?

 private ArrayList uniqueids = new ArrayList();
   uniqueids.add(modelClass.getUniqueId().toString());

Answer (score 2):

Get the List of `LatLng` from Server and Parse JSON Data using your Model Class and then now you can get all the points set your favorite loop to get point one by one and create Marker. I hope this solution will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a list of `LatLng` save a list of `ModelClass`. Then you will have the coordinates and the id you need to create the markers.